# Overloading + operator to concatenate two strings in C++ (Some doubts)

Tags: c++, string

I have just started learning C++ a few days back. I was given an assignment to demonstrate + operator overloading to concatenate two strings. I came up with this solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Strcpy{
private:
    char* wrd;
    int len;

public:
    Strcpy();
    Strcpy(char* );

    void Display();

    friend Strcpy operator + (Strcpy, Strcpy);
    friend Strcpy concatinator(Strcpy, Strcpy);
};

Strcpy :: Strcpy(){
    wrd = '\0';
    len = 0;
}

Strcpy :: Strcpy(char* w){
    int i; len = 0;
    for(i = 0; w[i] != '\0' ; i++)
        len ++;
    wrd = w;
}

void Strcpy :: Display(){
    cout << "\nOutput: " << wrd << " "<< len;
}


Strcpy operator + (Strcpy obj1, Strcpy obj2){
    Strcpy temp;
    int i;
    temp.wrd = new char[obj1.len + obj2.len];
    temp = concatinator(temp, obj1);
    temp = concatinator(temp, obj2);
    temp.wrd[temp.len] = '\0';
    return temp;

}

Strcpy concatinator(Strcpy obj, Strcpy temp){
    for(int i = 0; temp.wrd[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            obj.wrd[obj.len] = temp.wrd[i];
            obj.len++;
        }
    return obj;
}

int main(){
    Strcpy word, word_I("Hello"), word_II("World");
    word = word_I + word_II;
    word.Display();
    return 1;
}
```

Some things to be noted:

- **deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]** I realize this is being caused because I am converting an immutable type to a mutable one but what alternative approach can I try to get rid of this.
- I want to avoid using **friend functions**, but the overloaded operator needs two arguments which isn't possible if it remains a class member.
- The following line works the same even if it is changed, why is this happening:

  ```
  temp.wrd = new char[obj1.len + obj2.len];
  //changed to
  temp.wrd = new char[//any number here];
  ```
- I want avoid using **string functions** if that is possible at all.
- Whenever i try taking an input in the following form, it crashes:

  ```
  char* Strcpy :: get(){
      char* temp;
      cin >> temp;
      return temp;
  }

  int main(){
      Strcpy word;
      Strcpy word_I(word.get()), word_II(word.get());
      word = word_I + word_II;
      word.Display();
      return 1;
  }
  ```
- Lastly, I would appreciate any help that would help me improve on the existing solution and some explanation so as to why it is better and the mistakes I am making.

Comment: You have more fundamental problems to worry about. You are leaking memory. You are [violating the Rule Of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). You must fix these problems first, then worry about this.

Comment: Additionally in get you don't allocate any memory

Comment: A + operator inside a class can be used. The binary + has one argument - the 2nd. The first argument is the instance itself (i.e. this).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is totally right. Better learn C++ first before writing some code which you may have googled while programming and put together

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you for the information il start there.

Comment: do not remove information that changes the question so much. Edit and add information instead. And do not put javascript snippets in any other languages' code

Comment: Oh, sorry i'll keep this in mind @LưuVĩnhPhúc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings] I realize this is being caused because I am converting an immutable type to a mutable one but what alternative approach can I try to get rid of this.

You never modify `*w`, so you can use a pointer to const instead.

> I want to avoid using friend functions, but the overloaded operator needs two arguments which isn't possible if it remains a class member.

The first argument of a member operator overload is the implicit `this` pointer. If you declare `Strcpy Strcpy::operator+(const Strcpy&) const`, it will be a binary operator. That said, the friend operator is probably a better approach.

> The following line works the same even if it is changed, why is this happening:
>
> ```
> temp.wrd = new char[obj1.len + obj2.len];
> //changed to
> temp.wrd = new char[//any number here];
> ```

It will work as long as "any number" is large enough to contain the entire string. If you write outside of the bounds, the behaviour is undefined.

> Whenever i try taking an input in the following form, it crashes:
>
> ```
> char* temp;
> cin >> temp;
> ```

The stream extraction operator requires that a `char*` passed to it must point to an array sufficiently large to contain the user input. You forgot to initialize `temp`, so the requirement is not satisfied. As a result, the behaviour of the program is undefined. Solution: Allocate some memory and initialize `temp` to point to that memory.

The same bug occurs the constructor `Strcpy(char*)`. You don't initialize `this->wrd`, but you dereference it. Therefore the behaviour is undefined. The solution is the same as above.

Comment: Thanks for that last addition about initializing to an array before dereferencing and all the other inputs. Probably I will be looking up memory allocation before attempting the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this right

> I want to avoid using friend functions, but the overloaded operator
>   needs two arguments which isn't possible if it remains a class member.

your statement is wrong.

Sample for a binary + operator in a class:

```
#include <iostream>

class Int {
  private: int _i;
  public:
    Int(int i = 0): _i(i) { }
    Int operator + (const Int &i) const
    {
      return Int(_i + i._i);
    }
    int get() const { return _i; }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  Int i1(1), i2(2);
  Int i;
  i = i1 + i2;
  std::cout << "i: " << i.get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested with gcc on cygwin:

```
$ g++ -o test-op-plus test-op-plus.cc

$ ./test-op-plus.exe 
i: 3
```

Comment: What i meant to say was this:
Strcpy::operator+(Strcpy, Strcpy)' must take either zero or one argument|
Thank you for the information though, much appreciated.